# Custom Registration Page for Cognito User Pool

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-userpools

I have a Cognito User Pool and need to prompt users select their country from a dropdown list during registration. As far as I can tell, Cognito doesn't provide the ability to customize the registration page with a dropdown. Is there a way to redirect the "Sign Up" link in the Cognito sign-in page to point to a specific URL so I can provide my own registration page (and use the Cognito APIs to create the user)?

Or, if someone knows of a different way to solve this problem, I'm all ears.

My OIDC clients are websites (i.e., not a mobile apps) and I'm using the authorization code flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own registration page and use AWS cognito SDK or amplify to make calls to cognito. For example, if you are using javascript you can use the following code for your signup calls: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#signUp-property

Comment: I'm prepared to create my own registration page. My concern is getting them to the registration page. Normally, a "sign up" link is provide on a login page so that users who don't have an account can select that. I want to be able modify the href for the "Sign up" link on the Cognito-provided login page and point it to my own registration page. Is there a way to do that? Otherwise, I need to host the login and registration pages (which call Cognito APIs). Hosting the login page would then require me to be the equivalent of the OIDC auth endpoint (since clients point to the login URL).

Comment: You cannot modify any links on the cognito hosted GUI. You will need to host your own login and registration page.

Comment: Thank you, Ninad. That seems to mean I need to create an entire authorization endpoint since I have multiple websites that will be using OIDC/SSO. Those websites don't allow me to change the login page so I need an endpoint those websites can redirect (via OIDC) users to that includes a login page and (after credential verification) redirects the user browser with an authorization code back to the original website. The only authentication API that Cognito provides seems to be AdminInitiateAuth, which only returns Access and ID tokens, not authorization codes. I'll have to keep investigating.

Comment: Found anything?